# Yii2 - Show and Hide Div on Button Click is having issue

Tags: javascript, yii2

I am trying to hide and show a div on button click. By default, I hide the div. When I click the button, it works initially. But I observed that after few seconds, the div hides or shows on its own without button click.

**Button**

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 left-padding">
        <?= Html::a('<i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>'.Yii::t('app', ' Display Advanced Search'), [''], ['class' => 'btn btn-block btn-warning', 'onclick' => "advancedSearch()"]) ?>
    </div>
```

**Div to Hide or Show**

```html
    <div id="toggleSearch" class="col-xs-12" style="display:none">
    <div class="box"> 
        <div class="box-body table-responsive">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h4><strong><u>Advanced Search</u></strong></h4>
            </div>
   <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
       'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
   'method' => 'get']); ?>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12 no-padding"> 
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
          <?= $form->field($searchModel, 'zonal_office_id')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
                'data' => ArrayHelper::map(app\models\ZonalOffice::find()->all(),'id','zonal_office_name'),
                'language' => 'en',
                'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Zonal Office ...'],

             //   'disabled'=>'true',
                'pluginOptions' => [
                    'allowClear' => true
                ],
            ]); ?>        
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
   <?= $form->field($searchModel, 'state_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => 100, 'placeholder' => $searchModel->getAttributeLabel('state_name')]) ?>
    </div>   
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-lg-12"> 
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Click to Search', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>
</div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```html
<script>
function advancedSearch() {
    var x = document.getElementById("toggleSearch");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

What do I do to resolve the problem. Thanks

Comment: is it showing and hiding by itself or if you click anywhere other than the anchor ?

Comment: If I click on it it shows, but in just 1 or 2 seconds it hides by itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reason

It is because you are assigning the url parameter as an array `['']` with empty string, rather than a string with either `javascript:void(0)` or `'#.'`.

- When you provide it `['']` it will create the URL with the same page you are on means if your view loads on the URL `http://example.com/dashboard/search` it will append the same URL to the anchor. Similarly providing the empty string instead of an array will append the route `dashboard/search` to the `href` of the anchor. 
  In your case it is reloading the page that is why you get a feeling like it hides back, it actually reloads the page and goes back to initial state.

### Why it creates those URLs?

The `BaseHtml::a()` calls the [`Url::to($url);`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/helpers/BaseUrl.php#L211) which further calls the

- `static::toRoute($url, $scheme);` if the url is an array `['controller/action']` or empty `['']`.
- `Yii::$app->getRequest()->getUrl();` if the url provided is empty string `''`.
- Or adds the string as is if not empty, like `javascript:void(0)` or `'#.'`

So change your code to

### Solution 1

```
<?= Html::a('<i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>' . Yii::t('app', ' Display Advanced Search'), '#.', ['class' => 'btn btn-block btn-warning', 'onclick' => "advancedSearch()"]) ?>
```

### Solution 2

or use jquery to bind the javascript, but add a class to the anchor first with the name `advance_search`, remove the `onclick` attribute from the anchor.

```
<?= Html::a('<i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>' . Yii::t('app', ' Display Advanced Search'), '#.', ['class' => 'advance_search btn btn-block btn-warning']) ?>
```

and add the following on top of your view file

```
$js=<<< JS
        $("a.advance_search").on('click',function(e){
           e.preventDefault();
            var x = document.getElementById("toggleSearch");
            if (x.style.display === "none") {
                x.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                x.style.display = "none";
            }
        });
JS;
$this->registerJs($js,\yii\web\view::POS_READY);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the event handler is not bound on the same context as the listener is looking at for it to find.

If you bind the handler directly on the html element (as in the example you provided), the handler is expected to be available on the window object.

There's a quick fix for this; if you bind the handler explicitly to the window object. It's not the cleanest way, but it solves this problem.

```
<script>
window.advancedSearch = function advancedSearch() {
  var x = document.getElementById("toggleSearch");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

A cleaner approach would be to provide an `id` property to the item and bind the handler on the DOM element once the page completed loading.

eg:

```
<script>
function advancedSearch() {
  var x = document.getElementById("toggleSearch");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  document.getElementById("MyButton").onclick = advancedSearch;
});
</script>
```

Edit:
I put together an example on js fiddle that supports the behaviour:
https://jsfiddle.net/rv20yq7k/

Comment: Please can you explan  function(event) and ("MyButton")

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this function `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the link from working as it should, to avoid reloading the page because your button is a link and is reloading the page every time you click, and for that your "div" will hide again

```
function advancedSearch() {
    event.preventDefault(); // to prevent reload the page
    var x = document.getElementById("toggleSearch");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for my bad English